# How to check if given path is FILE or FOLDER?

Tags: windows, delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

There's some way to determine with precision if a given path is a FILE or FOLDER?

If yes, could show a example please? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the RTL's [`TPath.GetAttributes()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.IOUtils.TPath.GetAttributes), [`TFile.GetAttributes()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.IOUtils.TFile.GetAttributes) or [`TDirectory.GetAttributes()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.IOUtils.TDirectory.GetAttributes) method, eg:

```pascal
uses
  ..., System.IOUtils;

try
  if TFileAttribute.faDirectory in TPath{|TFile|TDirectory}.GetAttributes(path) then
  begin
    // path is a folder ...
  end else
  begin
    // path is a file ...
  end;
except
  // error ...
end;
```

Or, you can use the Win32 API [`GetFileAttributes()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfileattributesw) or [`GetFileAttributesEx()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfileattributesexw) function directly, eg:

```pascal
uses
  ..., Winapi.Windows;

var
  attrs: DWORD;
begin
  attrs := Windows.GetFileAttributes(PChar(path));
  if attrs = INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES then
  begin
    // error ...
  end
  else if (attrs and FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) <> 0 then
  begin
    // path is a folder ...
  end else
  begin
    // path is a file ...
  end;
end;
```

```pascal
uses
  ..., Winapi.Windows;

var
  data: WIN32_FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DATA;
begin
  if not Windows.GetFileAttributesEx(PChar(path), GetFileExInfoStandard, @data) then
  begin
    // error ...
  end
  else if (data.dwFileAttributes and FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) <> 0 then
  begin
    // path is a folder ...
  end else
  begin
    // path is a file ...
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Seeing WIN32 API option above, is realiable test `INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES` to check if file/folder exists?

Comment: [Potentially yes](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20071023-00/?p=24713), as long as you don't need to deal with `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_REPARSE_POINT`, which would require more work to determine if the target file/folder actually exists or not.

Comment: How do you know when to use TPath|TFile|TDirectory? You just receive a string. You don't know if it is a file or directory.

Comment: @GabrielMoraru I don't use them myself at all. However, if the file/folder exists, you can use `TPath.GetAttributes()` to differentiate between them (via the presence or lack of the `faDirectory` attribute).

Comment: "if the file/folder exists, you can use...." - Ok. But then my function (see my answer) should suffice. Right?

Comment: @GabrielMoraru your function will "work", but I would not recommend it, as it is less efficient

Comment: But you advocate using the functions as me (FileExists/DirectoryExists). How can my function be less efficient in this case?

Comment: @GabrielMoraru "*you advocate using the functions as me (FileExists/DirectoryExists)*" - I said no such thing. But, `FileExists()` and `DirectoryExists()` both use `GetFileAttributes()` internally. As for efficiency, your *original* function was doing 2 separate checks (using the same underlying API twice) which is less efficient than doing 1 single check, as the code in my answer is doing. However, you have since changed your code to remove one of the checks.

Comment: Sorry, I interpreted wrong your statement: "if the file/folder exists". I understand now.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Note: the folder must exist.
function IsFolder(CONST FullPath: string): boolean;
begin
 Result:= {NOT FileExists(FullPath) AND} DirectoryExists(FullPath);
end;
```

Comment: Doing 2 checks is overkill/redundant (and a race condition) when 1 check will suffice. See `GetFileAttributes()`/`TPath.GetAttributes()`

Comment: @RemyLebeau - I agree.